# Objective C- Slide to open app from homescreen

Tags: ios, objective-c

If anyone has a Starbucks app on their iPhone, you would see that when in or near a Starbucks, on  your lock screen is a sort of push notification, and you swipe it to open up the app right away, just like a text message on your lock screen. I was wondering if this is a difficult task to accomplish, and base its appearance of your location, so if I'm near a certain place, it would show up on my home screen. Is their a name for this and is it too difficult? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you need to use a notification. Read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html) and you will understand how to use it.

This is an example how to fire a local notification after certain time interval:

```
- (void) scheduleLocalNotificationWithMessage:(NSString*) msg andFireTime:(NSTimeInterval) time
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:time];
    notification.alertBody = msg;
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

In order to receive permanent location updates, [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_location_handling.htm) tutorial will help you.

To receive location updates in background choose app Target, then select Capabilities, then check Location Updates:
[image]

Good luck!

Comment: +1, OP will also need to use 'background app refresh' in order to monitor the location of the device